# SQL split 2 columns into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I apologize, I wrote these questions on my train ride home from my phone so I didn't have my existing code handy. I have figured some of it out but still need some help

1) Question 1 : Splitting after every 6th digit, basically I need to split my columns after every 5th digit so that 123456 creates to columns , ones with 12345 and a second with 6, I have tried using the code below with no result. there are no spaces or symbols , just digits.

`substring(COA.UserCode2,5,charindex('',COA.UserCode2)) as Account`,
 `substring(COA.UserCode2,6,charindex('',COA.UserCode2)) as Project`

2) Question 2: Splitting after every * , I can get the first one below to work (Fund)  but my cost center and Source don't work basically if I have a string like 1234*34*500, I need the column for fund to have 1234 ( This I got already) , my Cost center to say 34 and my source to say 500

`substring(COA.UserCode3, 1,charindex('*',COA.UserCode3)) as Fund,`
 `substring(COA.UserCode3, 3,charindex('*',COA.UserCode3)+1) as CostCenter,`
  `substring(COA.UserCode3, 1,charindex('*',COA.UserCode3)) as Source`

Comment: Is there a question here? Or do you want someone to write the code for you ?

Comment: Please search BOL for substring(), charindex(), patindex() functions and you will find all that you need. SO is not a code writing service

Comment: @ryadvaville , im not sure what you mean by do I expect someone to write my code for me , to my understanding this was a forum to ask question , and my question was very clear  1) could someone show me a sample of splitting a string every 6th digit and  2) can someone show me a sample of splitting a string after every * . if that's asking too much then I guess I misunderstood what the purpose of a forum is. I've answered 100's of questions in many forums and never felt the need to get smart with anyone , but then again I guess you know it all Master.

Answer (score 0):

For Question 1, replace

```
charindex('',COA.UserCode2)
```

with

```
len(COA.UserCode2)
```

(or just hard-code the length).

For Question 2, your Substring Start parameter for the 2nd and 3rd columns needs to factor in the length of the strings you have already chopped out in the preceeding columns. I would code this with nested select statments to make the code less clunky.